# conexão ssrs com PHP

Tags: php, reporting-services

Estou tentando conectar com o reporting services usando a ssrs sdk for PHP, 
eis o meu código de conexão:

```
<?php
    require_once 'bin/SSRSReport.php';


    define("UID", "********");
    define("PASWD", "*********");
    define("SERVICE_URL", "http://meu-pc:8080/ReportServer");
    try
    {
        $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);                
    }
    catch (SSRSReportException $serviceException)
    {
        echo $serviceException->GetErrorMessage();
    }
?>
```

ele me mostra o seguinte resultado:

```
array ( 
0 => 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', 
1 => 'Content-Length: 0', 
2 => 'WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', 
3 => 'Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 16:18:30 GMT', 
4 => 'Connection: close', )
Failed to connect to Reporting Service 
Make sure that the url (http://meu-pc:8080/ReportServer/) and credentials are correct!
```

Se alguém já tiver usado esta biblioteca ou conheça outra para conexão com o reporting services e poder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

Comment: Verifica no Firewall, se está permitida a porta 8080

Comment: sim, eu inclusive a utilizo em outros serviços, que obviamente não estão startados.